# Python Loading GeoJson Data :ValueError: Unhandled object

Tags: python, json

```
fg = folium.FeatureGroup(name = "My Map")

fg.add_child(folium.GeoJson(open('world.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8-sig'),name="geojson"))
```

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "map-copy.py", line 21, in <module>
    fg.add_child(folium.GeoJson(open('world.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8-sig'),name="geojson"))
  File "E:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\folium\features.py", line 495, in __init__
    raise ValueError('Unhandled object {!r}.'.format(data))
ValueError: Unhandled object <_io.TextIOWrapper name='world.json' mode='r' encoding='utf-8-sig'>.
```

Comment: This is basically impossible for us to answer. We don't know any context. You'll need to add some more information in order for us to help you.

Comment: What's your context?

Comment: I want to load a JSON file named "world.json" to the map object using GeoJson.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out finally.

```
 fg_addchild(folium.GeoJson(open("world.json",encoding = "utf-8-sig").read()))
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem. It works as Seasoner replay you should have jason on same folder

```
import folium
import pandas
import json
import codecs


map = folium.Map(location=[39.908298, 32.846302], zoom_start=6,\
                      control_scale = True, tiles='Stamen Terrain')

fg= folium.FeatureGroup(name='My Map')


fg.add_child(folium.Marker(location=[38.750093, 30.556405],popup="AFYON <br> Adres: Marulcu Mah. Hacı Felahi Cad. Gökpınar Apt. No:31/1 AFYONKARAHİSAR <br>Telefon : +90 272 214 49 13 ", icon=folium.Icon(color='green')))
fg.add_child(folium.Marker(location=[40.679107, 35.834749],popup="AMASYA <br> Adres: Dere Kocacık Mah. Mustafa Kemal Cad. Ferit Yıldırım İş Hanı No:3 AMASYA <br> Telefon: +90 358 212 83 39", icon=folium.Icon(color='green')))

fg.add_child(folium.GeoJson(open("world.json",encoding = "utf-8-sig").read()))

map.add_child(fg)
map.save("Map2.html")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fg.add_child(folium.GeoJson(open("world.json",encoding = "utf-8-sig").read()))
```

Answer (score 0):

**The solution:**

```
fg = folium.FeatureGroup(name="My Map")
fg.add_child(folium.GeoJson(open("world.json",encoding = "utf-8-sig").read()))
```

Comment: Edit your answer, please. You need to answer in a readable way.