# GeoJson usage in folium

Tags: python, json, geojson, folium

I have used GeoJson method in FeatureGroup of folium to add polygon layers to my map. I am getting some error. I have checked the syntax of this method.Everything is correct but still i am getting the error mentioned below in the image.

[image: The error is shown in the image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46369182/python-loading-geojson-data-valueerror-unhandled-object) . See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46378394/3437504) for resolution

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon the same issue.

From the documentation at https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/modules.html#folium.features.GeoJson you can see various examples of opening the geojson file.

```
>>> # Providing file that shall be embedded.
>>> GeoJson(open('foo.json'))
>>> # Providing filename that shall not be embedded.
>>> GeoJson('foo.json')
>>> # Providing dict.
>>> GeoJson(json.load(open('foo.json')))
>>> # Providing string.
>>> GeoJson(open('foo.json').read())
```

What worked for me was,

```
>>> GeoJson(open('foo.json').read())
```

Answer (score 0):

The data parameter in `GeoJson()` needs `string` to process, you sending it as a file `object`, in order to convert it to `string`, just add `read()` method at the end of `open()` to convert it to `string`.

Like this

```
fg.add_child(folium.GeoJson(data=(open("world.json", "r", encoding="utf-8-sig")).read()))
```

That's all, no over will pop up then.