# How to load GeoJson file properly?

Tags: python, json, geocoding, geojson, folium

I have a `geojson` file of Moscow districts that is avaliable at

http://gis-lab.info/data/mos-adm/mo.geojson

So, I can't load it properly.

These ideas does not help:

- [GeoJSON data not displaying in Python folium map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42107268/geojson-data-not-displaying-in-python-folium-map)
- [GeoJson usage in folium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46611439/geojson-usage-in-folium)

I tried to create a map and then add a layer on it.

```
 import folium

m = folium.Map(location = [55.7522200,37.6156000], zoom_start_13)

folium.GeoJson(open('mo.geojson')).add_to(m)'
```

this does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `folium.GeoJson(open('mo.geojson').read()).add_to(m)`

This reads the contents of the file and passes the string to folium.

Comment: Got this error: `UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 907334: character maps to <undefined>`

So, I have added `encoding - 'utf-8'` parameter,  now it works. Thanks A lot!!!